# Converting a column from a table into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

My goal is to convert a column from a data table in R into a matrix so that I may incorporate it into later use in my project.
From a dataset, I saved all of the values from the 'AGE' column into a variable:

```
AGE.data <- sample_data(phy.norm.new)[,'AGE']
```

Doing so yielded:

> Sample Data:        [240 samples by 1 sample variables]:
>
> AGE
>
> AGE.109  56
>
> AGE.236  50
>
> AGE.201  34
>
> AGE.96   64
>
> AGE.21   66
>
> AGE.56   54
>
> AGE.64   65
>
> AGE.225  76
>
> AGE.24   70
>
> AGE.57   84
>
> AGE.117  50
>
> AGE.177  65
>
> ...

(Not all rows have been typed in this blockquote, only a few in order to illustrate what it looks like in the console).

In order to convert the values from this column into a matrix, I used:

```
mat.AGE.data <- matrix(AGE.data)
```

However, I do not get a 240-row by 1-column matrix displaying all of the age values. Instead, this displays in the console.

> mat.AGE.data

```
     [,1]       
[1,] Integer,240
```

I've read the comprehensive R tutorial, but I'm still unsure of how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Using         str(AGE.data) I got this output:

> 'data.frame':  240 obs. of  1 variable:
>
> Formal class 'sample_data' [package "phyloseq"] with 4 slots
>
> ..@ .Data    :List of 1
>
> .. ..$ : int  56 50 34 64 66 54 65 76 70 84 ...
>
> ..@ names    : chr "AGE"
>
> ..@ row.names: chr  "CRC.109" "CRC.236" "CRC.201" "CRC.96" ...
>
> ..@ .S3Class : chr "data.frame"

```
dput(head(AGE.data, 10))
```

> new("sample_data"
>
> , .Data = list(c(56L, 50L, 34L, 64L, 66L, 54L, 65L, 76L, 70L, 84L))
>
> , names = "AGE"
>
> , row.names = c("AGE.109", "AGE.236", "AGE.201", "AGE.96", "AGE.21", "AGE.56",
>
> ```
>                "AGE.64", "AGE.225", "AGE.24", "AGE.57")
> ```
>
> , .S3Class = "data.frame"
>
> )

Comment: Please check the `str(AGE.data)`. Also, it is not clear whether this is a `data.table`, or `table` or `data.frame`

Comment: @akrun I edited my post to include the output of str(AGE.data).

Comment: Could you `dput` the output i.e. `dput(head(AGE.data, 10))`.  Seems like it is a list output.

Comment: @akrun I've edited my post to include it

Comment: It is giving me errors.  I don't have the package `phyloseq` installed.  Hopefully, someone will respond.

Comment: I used [this link](http://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/install) to install the package. But thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @akrun 
I've resolved the issue: I used `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(AGE.data)),nrow=nrow(AGE.data))` and the matrix I got was correct. Thanks for the help otherwise!

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to solve.

Comment: `matrix(AGE.data[[1]])` may work as well

Answer (score 0):

The original poster solved the issue by using `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(AGE.data)),nrow=nrow(AGE.data))`